# Why I can't receive message from server?

Tags: android, sockets

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

 private EditText txtLoginName;
 private EditText txtLoginPassword;
 private Button btnLogin;
 private Button btnReset;

 private static final int FLAG_LOGIN_SUCCESS=1;
 private static final String MSG_LOGIN_ERROR="登录出错";
 private static final String MSG_LOGIN_SUCCESS="登录成功";
 private static ProgressDialog dialog;

 public static final String MSG_LOGIN_FAILED="登录名或密码出错";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //初始化控件
    init();

    //点击登录，响应事件
    this.btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final String loginName=txtLoginName.getText().toString();
            final String loginPassword=txtLoginPassword.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), loginName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), loginPassword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(dialog==null)
            {
                dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            }
            dialog.setTitle("请等待");
            dialog.setMessage("登录中...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            MyRunnable mRunnable=new MyRunnable(loginName,loginPassword);

            Thread thread=new Thread(mRunnable);

            thread.start();
        }
    });

    //点击重置，响应事件
    this.btnReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtLoginName.setText("");
            txtLoginPassword.setText("");

        }
    });

}
private static class IHandler extends Handler
{
    private final WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

    public IHandler(MainActivity activity)
    {
        mActivity=new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        if(dialog!=null)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        int flag=msg.what;
        switch (flag) {
        case 0:
            String errorMsg=(String)msg.getData().getString("ErrorMsg");
            ((MainActivity)mActivity.get()).showTip(errorMsg);
            break;
        case FLAG_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            ((MainActivity)mActivity.get()).showTip(MSG_LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void showTip(String str)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private IHandler handler=new IHandler(this);
private void init()
{
    this.txtLoginName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       this.txtLoginPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
       this.btnLogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       this.btnReset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
} 
class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{

    private  ObjectInputStream readObject;
    private  ObjectOutputStream writeObject;
    private Socket socket;
    private ReturnMessage returnMessage;
    private String loginName;
    private String loginPassword;
    LoginMessage msg;

    public MyRunnable(String loginName,String loginPassword)
    {
        this.loginName=loginName;
        this.loginPassword=loginPassword;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //userService.userLogin(loginName, loginPassword);
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.114", 8000);
            writeObject = getOutObjectStream(socket);
            readObject = getInObjectStream(socket);
            msg=new LoginMessage(loginName, loginPassword);
            writeObject.writeObject(msg);
            writeObject.flush();
            returnMessage =(ReturnMessage)readObject.readObject();
            Log.d("hehehehe", returnMessage.getStr());
            socket.close();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(FLAG_LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        }
        catch(SecurityException e)
        {
            /*e.printStackTrace();*/
            Message msg=new Message();
            Bundle data=new Bundle();
            data.putSerializable("ErrorMsg", "1");
            msg.setData(data);
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            /*e.printStackTrace();*/
            Message msg=new Message();
            Bundle data=new Bundle();
            data.putSerializable("ErrorMsg","2");
            msg.setData(data);
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    private  ObjectOutputStream getOutObjectStream(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {
    return new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  
    }
    private ObjectInputStream getInObjectStream(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {   
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    return new ObjectInputStream(bis); 
   }
}
}
```

This is a simple login server program, run it can send messages to the server, but it can not receive the message from server, and sometimes crash, who can help me?

Comment: where does it crash 'sometimes'?

Comment: This is a wall of code. Please post only the relevent sections and make sure that it's indented properly.

Comment: When I first run the program，it crash,but just a few times like this,I don't kown what happened,and I also can not receive message from server

Comment: 'It crashes' and 'can not receive' are not problem descriptions. Don't create new `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` per message. Use the same pair for the life of the socket, at both ends. You haven't posted any server code, which makes your question unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated an object in class scope with passing `this` to its constructor.

```
private IHandler handler = new IHandler(this);
```

You should avoid this, because the object `this` has not been still initialized. So you may want to instantiate your handler in one of Activity's methods (For example, `onCreate` method).